# Option Menu Animation

Tags: android, animation, optionmenu

How can i give a slide down animation like this :

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="100%" />
</set>
```

for " Option Menu " Opening .like this animation :

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just add this line into your style.xml 
please add this on your Application main Style that you define in manifest

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:popupAnimationStyle">@style/Animation</item>
</style>
```

style.xml :

```
<style name="Animation">
<item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/your_specific_animation</item>
<item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/your_specific_animation</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't worked for me. I'm trying to actually disable the animations entirely.

Answer (score 1):

create a xml in anim folder

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:fillAfter="true">

<scale
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />
```

In activity call the animation

```
 Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.myanimation);
    image.startAnimation(animation);//place the syntax in options menu
```

Comment: i create option menu like this :
    "@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }"
i have not any image .